# C#.Net saxon9he-api(Version 9.6.0.7) throw out of memory exception for large XML file(>4GB)

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, saxon

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.IsLineNumbering = true;
documentBuilder.WhitespacePolicy = WhitespacePolicy.PreserveAll;
XdmNode _XdmNode = documentBuilder.Build(xmlDocumentToEvaluate);

////System.Exception: Error in ExecuteRules method ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyTree.ensureNodeCapacity`enter code here`(Int16 )
   at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyTree.addNode(Int16 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
   at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder.makeTextNode(CharSequence chars, Int32 len)
   at net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder.characters(CharSequence chars, Int32 locationId, Int32 properties)
   at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.characters(CharSequence chars, Int32 locationId, Int32 properties)
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushTee.copyEvent(Int32 )
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushTee.next()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullConsumer.consume()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushCopier.copy()
   at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendPullSource(PullSource , Receiver , ParseOptions )
   at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Source source, Receiver receiver, ParseOptions options)
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Source source, ParseOptions parseOptions)
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Source source)
   at Saxon.Api.DocumentBuilder.Build(XmlReader reader)
   at Saxon.Api.DocumentBuilder.Build(XmlNode source)
```

//// Saxon API has any suggestions. If anyone have proper solution then please advise here.

////Processor: CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.10 GHz
////Memory: 32GB, x64-based processor

Comment: At that scale  you'll need a streaming or streaming + node-at-a-time parsing approach.  I don't know about Saxon, but .NET has a streaming XmlReader built-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-5.0

Comment: Then investigate Saxon streaming: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/sourcedocs/streaming/

Comment: I am still investigating and looking for some help if Saxon API has any suggestions.

Comment: Are you running XPath or XQuery or XSLT against your input XML? Do you work and need to work with both a Microsoft `System.Xml.XmlNode` as well Saxon's  `XdmNode`?

Answer (score 0):

4Gb is way too big for a conventional in-memory transformation.

If the processing is intrinsically streamable - that is, if the output has some kind of linear relationship to the input - then you should be able to implement it as a streamable XSLT 3.0 transformation using Saxon-EE, but (a) you'll need to buy a license, and (b) you'll almost certainly need to make some code changes to the stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you Michael Kay. Please send me the link for Saxon-EE implemention in C#.Net.

Comment: @DipakShinde, Saxon EE is a commercial product of Saxonica, find details at https://www.saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml.

Comment: Michael Kay and Martin Honnen, How much XML size will support by Saxon EE edition?

Comment: @DipakShinde, if you use pure XSLT 3 streaming with Saxon EE the size is not limited. But it is XSLT 3 you use and you will need to let Saxon process the input by providing a Stream to e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/Xslt30Transformer.html#ApplyTemplates(Stream,Uri,XmlDestination), I am not sure you can expect it to work against a huge XML document your code first loads as a `Ssytem.Xml.XmlDocument`.

Comment: In above code xmlDocumentToEvaluate is XMLDocument and I am converting it into XdmNode. So here it throw exception.

Comment: You could try `DocumentBuilder.Wrap()` instead of `DocumentBuilder.Build()`. But you're running close to the limits, it might break somewhere else. Or you could try building a Saxon tree directly from XML, bypassing the DOM.

Comment: @DipakShinde, I saw that you use an XmlDocument first but if you work with two trees (XmlDocument and then XdmNode) of the same 4 GB input document you are obviously storing at least twice the amount of data you need to run Saxon. And of course the idea about XSLT and streaming is to *not* build a full tree of the huge document, rather to stream through node by node and only materialize the stuff you need. You haven't shown what you use Saxon for and it is hard to tell whether streaming helps doing that in a less memory intensive way, but `XmlDocument` as the input doesn't work with streaming.

Comment: The only way with HE and `System.Xml.XmlDocument/XmlNode` would be not to load the full document into an `XmlDocument`, but rather to use an `XmlReader` for forwards only pull parsing and materialize any node you want as a tree with `ReadNode` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.readnode?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlDocument_ReadNode_System_Xml_XmlReader_, on that you can then run Saxon as before.

Comment: @MichaelKay DocumentBuilder.Wrap() solution is working but for "public XdmValue Evaluate();" method is showing below error:                                                                                            Unsupported node type in DOM! XmlDeclaration instance System.Xml.XmlDeclaration.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  We are using Saxon.API for Evaluate the query, returning the result as an XdmValue (that is, a sequence  of nodes and/or atomic values). An XdmValue representing the results of the query.

Comment: Evaluate method description:
Evaluate the query, returning the result as an XdmValue (that is, a sequence of nodes and/or atomic values).Returns:  An XdmValue representing the results of the query
Exceptions: T:Saxon.Api.DynamicError: Throws a DynamicError if any run-time failure occurs while evaluating the  query. @MichaelKay please guide here.

Comment: The big question is, what's the query? For example, does it involve sorting?

Comment: In query we are filtering data.

Comment: XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
compiler.DeclareNamespace(_currentNamespace, _currentNamespaceURI);
XQueryExecutable executable = compiler.Compile(xquery);
evaluator = executable.Load();

In "evaluator" it show below exception error:"Unsupported node type in DOM! XmlDeclaration instance System.Xml.XmlDeclaration." @MichaelKay Please guide here.

Comment: @DipakShinde, Saxon 9.6 is rather old so perhaps you can move to Saxon 10. At least with that version I don't get any such exception when wrapping an XmlDocument (with an XML declaration) with a Saxon DocumentBuilder and using the XdmNode as the ContextItem to an XQueryEvaluator. Other than that I think, if you hit a bug, it is better to report it with the exact details at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/. There is an old issue https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1759 on the Java side that got fixed.

Comment: @DipakShinde, consider to post new issues as separate questions with a minimal but complete description in the question text, it is very hard to follow up anything here in the comment section.